# Oracle change initialization parameter with "deferred" keyword

Tags: oracle, configuration

The description of ***deferred*** and ***scope*** keyword is listed below (extracted from Oracle documentation). The meaning of them gives me an indication that ***deferred*** can just use the ***memory*** scope. Is my understanding right? Thanks.

> ***DEFERRED***
>
> The DEFERRED keyword sets or modifies the value of the
> parameter for future sessions that connect to the database. Current
> sessions retain the old value.
>
> ***SCOPE***
>
> The SCOPE clause lets you specify when the change takes effect.
> Scope depends on whether you started up the database using a
> traditional plain-text parameter file (pfile) or server parameter file
> (spfile).
>
> *MEMORY* indicates that the change is made in memory, takes effect
> immediately, and persists until the database is shut down. If you
> started up the database using a parameter file (pfile), then this is
> the only scope you can specify.
>
> *SPFILE* indicates that the change is made in the server parameter
> file. The new setting takes effect when the database is next shut down
> and started up again. You must specify SPFILE when changing the value
> of a static parameter that is described as not modifiable in Oracle
> Database Reference.
>
> *BOTH* indicates that the change is made in memory and in the server
> parameter file. The new setting takes effect immediately and persists
> after the database is shut down and started up again.
>
> If a server parameter file was used to start up the database, then
> BOTH is the default. If a parameter file was used to start up the
> database, then MEMORY is the default, as well as the only scope you
> can specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked experimentally (Oracle 11.1) that actually ALTER SYSTEM ... DEFERRED SCOPE=SPFILE is allowed, although it seems to me that DEFERRED is ignored in this context. Also SCOPE=BOTH and SCOPE=MEMORY are allowed, obviously.

What you cannot do (the manual that you quote overlooked it) is ALTER SYSTEM ... DEFERRED on the parameter that has (V$PARAMETER.ISSYS_MODIFIABLE, V$PARAMETER.ISSES_MODIFIABLE) = (IMMEDIATE, FALSE). This results in:

```
ORA-02096: specified initialization parameter is not modifiable with this option
```